# SonarQube and migration to multi-module project with preserving history

Tags: sonarqube

We're in process of migration of a single Maven project that has been analyzed in SonarQube 4.5.4 into a multi-module Maven project.

The SonarQube analyzing is going to be migrated to the Parent project so that the old and new modules would be analyzed all-in-one.

During the analyzing we receive an error:
'The project '...' is already defined in SonarQube but not as a module of project '...:Parent''

The obvious solution is to remove the old project from SonarQube, however it means removal of all historical information.

How can we achieve both goals:

- migrate to multi-module project
- keep history of analyzing of the existing project (that should be a child of the new multi-module project)
  ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SonarQube does not allow to group several existing projects into a single one. So you won't be able to achieve your 2 goals.

The only thing you can do is to update the key of each existing project on SonarQube (for instance, you can add "_OLD" suffix on their key). This will allow you to:

- Keep the history for those projects - but they won't evolve any longer
- Make it possible to analyze successfully the new multi-module project

To know how to update project key, please read [the documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Project+Administration#ProjectAdministration-UpdatingProjectKey).

Comment: thanks. Might it be an idea to put a feature request to support this scenario in future?

Comment: Could be, but the use case is too rare to get priority over more important topics.